# Automate User Password Change using Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I would like to change a user password if it exists, but I get this error

here my code

```
     - name: Check for foo user
       with_items: foo
       changed_when: false
       command: grep {{ item }} -q /etc/passwd
       register: find_user


     - name: Update foo user's Password
       user:
         name: foo
         update_password: always
         password: $6$rounds=656000$ZjMwlMPWqwGKF1nY$JbarjwHGtlr5PD3Yqfb5phz18gnHujSgmpD29DxsXQ7a7UdhuO
       when: find_user is changed


TASK [Check for foo user] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.56.124]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "grep -w 'foo' /etc/passwd", "delta": "0:00:00.003024", "end": "2019-07-01 12:59:45.966160", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-07-01 12:59:45.963136", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `command` task you have is having an exit code = 1 when the username does not exist in the /etc/passwd file:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ grep foo -q /etc/passwd
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ echo $?
1
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ grep root -q /etc/passwd     
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ echo $?
0
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$
```

What you can do, is instruct this task to NOT fail when exit code from the `grep` command is not 0 or 1. To do that you need to add this clause in the command task:

```
failed_when: find_user.rc !=0 and find_user.rc !=1
```

The whole task would look like:

```
  - name: Check for foo user
    with_items: foo
    changed_when: false
    command: grep {{ item }} -q /etc/passwd
    register: find_user
    failed_when: find_user.rc !=0 and  find_user.rc !=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [getent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/getent_module.html#getent-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) module to test the existence of the user.

```
- name: Read passwd
  getent:
    database: passwd

- name: Update foo users password
  user:
    name: foo
    update_password: always
    password: ...
  when: "'foo' in getent_passwd"
```